# Sorting/Ordering list by character vector

Tags: r

Apologies that my question was unclear. It was my interpretation of the following assignment question:

Create a list (named mylist) that consists of one character vector (“J”,“A”,“G”,”B”,”H”,”E”,”C”,”F”,”D”,”I”), one numeric vector (10 random values from rnorm), and a matrix of size 10 x 10 (containing integer 1 to 100). After that you will provide a way of sorting the rows of all components (character, numeric and matrix) of mylist based on the order of the sorted character list. Finally, do a matrix times vector multiplication of the sorted second component and the third (integer) component (you will need to extract and convert these components to suitable modes).

Based on the code above, write a function that reads one character vector (of size n), one numeric vector (of size n) and one matrix (of size n x n). Then sorts the rows of all components based on the character vector, performs matrix times vector multiplication, combines the output of the multiplication with the input into a data frame that should be the output of the function.

Comment: It's unclear how your data structure looks exactly, and how you want to have the matrix sorted. Please, [edit] your Q and provide a [mcve] and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to extract the `character` vector separately, `order` it and then use `lapply to`order the elements

```
i1 <- order(lst$vec1) #assuming that the character `vector` is named `vec1`
lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(x) if(is.vector(x)) x[i1] else x[i1,])
```